# Is there a class or id that will cause an ad to be blocked by most major adblockers?

Tags: html, advertising, adblock

Is there a general class or ID for a html element that a high majority of popular adblockers will block on a website it has no information for.
My intention is to have my advertisement blocked, avoiding automatic blocking is easy enough...
I was thinking of maybe lending some ids or classes from big advertisment companies that area already being fought off quite actively.
right now my html

```
<ul id=partners>
 <li class=advertisment><a href=# class=sponsor><img class=banner></a></li>
</ul>
```

Will this work or is there a more solid approach?

Comment: Why would you want to block your advertisements? If you don't want them, couldn't you just delete the mark-up and save yourself and your users the trouble?

Comment: Shouldn't you also have `rel="nofollow"` on a sponsored (paid for) link?

Comment: @w3d Just assume the example markup has been reduced to what's necessary for the actual question. Nofollow is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Su' But `rel="nofollow"` could be another metric that adblockers use to help decide what is or isn't an advertisement...?

Comment: @w3d Why? Nofollow was originally conceived of in terms of spam links in comments. It has nothing to do with advertising.

Comment: @Su' Because [Google suggests using nofollow on paid advertising links](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66736). `rel="nofollow"` is _one way_ to prevent passing PageRank. And "links purchased for advertising" should not pass PageRank. Granted, there are other ways to do this, but since the OP wants to be as open as possible to the adblockers that this is an advert then I was just thinking that maybe an easy to find `rel="nofollow"` attribute _might_ provide an additional cue?

Comment: Google might suggest using `<div>` to put ads in, but it doesn't follow that you can assume all `<div>` usage is for adverts. The number of false positives for `rel="nofollow"` would still be pretty huge

Comment: @Gareth I'm not suggesting that all `rel="nofollow"` links should be treated as adverts, but merely an additional metric that _might_ be used in order to deduce that an arbitrary block of HTML markup pertains to be an advertisement. `rel="nofollow"` is used in [the EasyList filters for ABP](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) in order to identify and block certain adverts so it does have some relevance.

Answer (score 3):

Adblockers use a variety of techniques to block ads. They block them by domain or IP address, they also block them based on ad size. So if your ads are a common ad size, they should automatically be blocked.

But if you want to offer more clues via class and ID names, use a class since you can put as many names in it as you want. I'd then stick with obvious ad keywords like, "ad", "advertisement", "advert", etc.

Comment: URLs (subdomain, folder, etc.) are also a big one. By default ABP blocks all of the stylesheets on Google's AdWords/AdSsense sites because of this. He can also check the most popular ABP lists to see what the most common filters are.

Comment: Where can I find these lists @Lèsemajesté

Comment: @Moak: If you search Firefox Add-Ons for "AdBlock Plus" you should find at least some of these add-on lists. The one that ABP comes with by default is [EasyList](https://easylist.adblockplus.org). If you search Chrome Add-ons, there might be similar add-on lists for ABP for Chrome. Otherwise, search google for ["AdBlock Plus filter lists"](https://www.google.com/search?q=AdBlock+Plus+filter+lists).